# Android Broadcast Receiver fails if network connection is lost?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, network-connection

I have a Service and I use a Broadcast receiver to communicate between my activity and the service. When I kill my network connection by turning off wifi and Mobile Data, my broadcast receiver no longer calls the `onReceive()` method. Is this normal and is there any workaround?

Comment: Impossible to answer without code. `BroadcastReceiver`s have nothing to do with your network connection (except, of course, if you register a receiver for network status changes). I'd guess your code is broken... please post it.

Comment: Essentially, what I wanted to know, is if loosing my network connection would affect my Broadcast receiver and you answered that. So now I know the issue is in my code and I can debug that...

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was that when the network connection was dropped (wifi or mobile data) , my onStop() override was being called in my Activity that launched the service. In the onStop() method I was unregistering my Broadcast receiver....so thats why after I lost my network connection I could no longer communicate from my service back to the parent Activity .
Maybe someone can explain why onStop() is called when the  network connection is lost...

Comment: That might be a separate question up there. It's unlikely anyone will read the question hidden in your answer.